# How to write htaccess rules in shorten url format to grab code and query param

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to grab "xyz" & "12" in GET request.

This is my actual URL: http://www.domain.com/xyz?a=12

My code not working:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)?a=([0-9]*) click.php?short=$1&acc=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `QUERY_STRING` to capture query string.

Replace your current code by this one

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^a=([0-9]*)$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^()$
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ click.php?short=$1&acc=%1 [L]
```

Comment: I copy paste your code It just track short variable. acc variable is just coming blank..     Array
(
    [short] => xyz
    [acc] => 
)

Comment: Sorry, small distraction error. You can try again with edited code, will be working as expected now

Comment: Wow thats fix the problem but another problem found after this new code.. Now URL without query param is giving 404 error http://www.domain.com/xyz

Comment: This is normal behaviour regarding on the code above. What do you want as a result when you go to `/xyz` without any query string ?

Comment: If url is http://www.domain.com/xyz its not working.. it should return short=xyz & acc=null or blank.

Comment: Great its working. I will mark it as answer. Just little issue is if url is like: http://www.domain.com/xyz?a= It still showing 404. But nevermind i will play with code now to fix it.. Thanks for help..

Comment: I edited my answer to make it work for `?a=`. Glad it worked, you're welcome !